# Logoff button doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a logoff buttton which show me this message when i try to click logout on my application here is a message that i get

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of
>   non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult LogOff(Int32)' in
>   'Web_Site_Portal.Controllers.AccountController'. An optional
>   parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as
>   an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters

here is my code

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-raised" @Html.ActionLink("Logout", "LogOff", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "logOff" })<div class="ripple-container"></div></a>
```

Controller

```
// POST: /Account/LogOff
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult LogOff()
        {
            AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/LogOff
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult LogOff(int id)
        {
            AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
```

Comment: Just as the error states, the `LogOff()` method requires an `int` parameter.  You're not providing one.  What parameter do you need to provide?

Answer (score 4):

You have a `int` paramter in your `LogOff` action which seems to be wrong. You don't need this paramter because you are logging off the current logged on user. I see that your LogOff link has an `id` route parameter witch is a string. Why is that? If you need it you must change paramter type of `LogOff` action to string.

**Edit**

You have two actions that do the same thing. If you want your LogOff action to work with both `GET` and `POST` methods, then remove `[HttpGet]` and `[HttpPost]` from actions. All you need is this:

```
public ActionResult LogOff()
{
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Comment: i have done that and now i get this message "The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present."

Comment: You have `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute before your action. You also should add `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` in your form.